# file_get_contents fails for one particular folder

Tags: php, windows, permissions, file-get-contents, icacls

I'm using Windows platform -

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('C:/Apache24/htdocs/../zip/myfile.pdf');
```

This works absolutely fine but

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('C:/Apache24/htdocs/../zip/user@domain.com/myfile.pdf');
```

where user@domain.com is my folder name.

This fails and returns an error in the log as -
failed to open stream: No such file or directory'...

I replaced the name of the folder with newFolder and it worked fine without any error.

I assume that the issue lies with the Folder Naming. How can I overcome this without changing the folder name?

Comment: But does the file `myfile.pdf` exist in the `zip` folder? According to the error, it doesn't...

Comment: @Jerodev Yes myfile.pdf exists inside newFolder as well as zip. It works for zip but not for newFolder